# Datastage: parallel jobs often get stuck

Tags: parallel-processing, datastage

**When running parallel jobs in datastage, the jobs often get stuck like this:**[image]

**It seems the jobs log files or status files are locked, cause I clean up resource in Director(by clicking "log out all") then the jobs go ahead(in a sequence job) or get crashed.**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This could also be an effect of a complex query being executed against a database. While the action is in the database - before rows are retrieved - you will not see any log entries.

Comment: I'm sure it's nothing about the database. It seems to happen randomly. For example, I use a sequence job to call parallel jobs using a loop activity, each time passing a different parameter. The job will get stuck in a random iteration ( iteration 18 or iteration 22 e.g.)